# PHP RegEx not matching a string that it should match

Tags: php, regex

This is driving me insane...

I have the following code:

```php
    # open pdf
    $pdf = file_get_contents('myfile.pdf');

    echo("RE 1:\n");
    preg_match('/^[0-9]+ 0 obj.*\/Contents \[ ([0-9]+ [0-9]+) R \\]/msU', $pdf, $m);
    var_dump($m);

    echo("\nRE 2:\n");
    preg_match('/^8 0 obj.*\/Contents \[ ([0-9]+ [0-9]+) R \\]/msU', $pdf, $m);
    var_dump($m);
```

The file *myfile.pdf* contains the following text:

```
...
8 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 2 0 R
/Resources 6 0 R
/Contents [ 5 0 R ]
>>
endobj
...
```

The only difference between those two regular expressions is the numeric range at the beginning of the string. Yet I get the following output:

```
RE 1:
array(0) {
}

RE 2:
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(78) "8 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 2 0 R
/Resources 6 0 R
/Contents [ 5 0 R ]"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "5 0"
}
```

I would expect both regular expressions to return similar results, but the regular expression with the numeric range at the start (*RE 1*) doesn't return any results. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

### Update

After adding `preg_last_error()`, I am getting `PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR`. How can I fix that?

Comment: @Emma Yes, that is what I'm trying to capture. It works perfectly on regex101.com, but not in my code.

Comment: Both of your regexes work fine at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ so it could be that your PHP or PCRE version is causing a headache?

Comment: Try using [`preg_last_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-last-error.php) to see if it gives you any hints.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Good call! I am getting PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR.

Comment: Check your `php.ini` file and see what [`pcre.backtrack_limit`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php#ini.pcre.backtrack-limit) is set to or use `echo ini_get( 'pcre.backtrack_limit' );` if you don't have access to `php.ini`

Comment: It's commented out: ;pcre.backtrack_limit=100000. So I assume it's using the default value of 100000. That seems quite high though, no?

Comment: One would hope, yes. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9692029/2191572) alludes to an issue with brace nesting so maybe try `\]` instead of `\\]`?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I tried that, exact same result.

Comment: Try it like this https://3v4l.org/LfZpX

Comment: @Thefourthbird fourth bird I am trying to capture the Contents string. It's coming up with no matches though?

Comment: It is in the first capturing group. Using preg_match_all for example https://3v4l.org/ddmRY Only use the `/m` flag

Comment: @Thefourthbird This is my script and output: https://pastebin.com/PrHD5vgv

Comment: I have used the example data from the question, perhaps the data from the pdf differs a bit. Is is always structured like that? Can you share some more data from the pdf?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197185/discussion-between-ryan-steffer-and-the-fourth-bird).

Comment: Perhaps a bit less restrictive https://regex101.com/r/5NdmS6/1

Comment: I get no matches with that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you might be designing an expression that would somewhat look like,

```
[0-9]+\s+0\s+obj\b.*?\/Contents\s+\[\s*([0-9]+\s+[0-9]+)\s+R\s*\]
```

on `s` mode.

#### Test

```
$re = '/[0-9]+\s+0\s+obj\b.*?\/Contents\s+\[\s*([0-9]+\s+[0-9]+)\s+R\s*\]/s';
$str = '8 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 2 0 R
/Resources 6 0 R
/Contents [ 5 0 R ]
>>
endobj

8 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 2 0 R
/Resources 6 0 R
/Contents [ 5 0 R ]
>>
endobj';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/3xjtx7/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/3xjtx7/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: OP is using `/msU` so their `.` matches everything including newlines.

Comment: Yes, but that RE does work. And my output of preg_last_error() is PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR. So that's why mine doesn't work I guess. But I'm not sure what causes that...

Comment: Yours works with /msU. I'm wondering if it's the word boundary you used... Testing more things now.

Comment: Ok, yours works because you added the .*? quantifier. I am already using the /U modifier, which means _Ungreedy_. But then your .*? reverses that. But I need it to be ungreedy, as there are many instances of this string I'm trying to capture.

Comment: I see that. It will fail in regex101.com. But both are acceptable in PHP. I have tried both and they yield the exact same result.

Comment: Yes, confusing to say the least. But PHP seems to interpret it either way. I guess because a \\ could be a literal \, but when it's before a ], it might assume you're trying to escape the ], so it just rolls it together. I don't know...